# query about UI for all website developers any language

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, user-controls

I have a social website to make.
I have listen from many developers that ***First Expression is the last expression*** so for that i am preparing myslef.

The problem is that a user can disable javascript by himself.
I have to use a lot of scripts in my site.So on home page i have many animations made by using javascript and jquery . **What i want is that how can i check whether user has disable the javascript** & suppose If he has disable it then take it to some other page which have no javascript mean alternative page.

**Should i do it?
How can i make this check?**
Hope you will under stand . Thanks in advance.

Comment: The terms you're looking for are "graceful degredation" and "progress enhancement".  Both are valid.  More info: https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement

Comment: @freedomn-m Well that topic is nice and have all the answers i want.But my last question is still remaining ,question is there any way to enable javascript on single click.

Comment: That's why it's a comment, not an answer...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but you can't enable/disable javascript from a click on a webpage, that would be a *huge* security issue.

Comment: ok now i understand what is the matter.Thanks man.

Comment: I do not know why people rate questions negative.Questions are asked when some one do not know about it.Idiots!

Comment: Wasn't me, but seems to frequently be when there's no code.   No-one else has commented that this is off-topic and seems ok.  Might be because you put "please don't rate it negative" ... people will -ve vote just for that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127564/discussion-between-awais-ahmad-and-freedomn-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<noscript>
      <style>html{display:none;}</style>
      <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0.0;url=nojs.php">
</noscript>
```

That's what i got.I just redirect that user(without javascript) to another page.My requirement is full filled now.